# C while loop is printing extra number

Tags: c, while-loop

Can someone help me. My code is printing an extra number
It's suppose to work like this:
if is N=38
then it's suppose to print 
32.0
33.8
35.6
37.4

but mine prints
32.0
33.8
35.6
37.4
39.2
how do i get rid of the last number. I'm still a beginner so i'm quite bad at this

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    
    int main(){
        int i, n;
        float f;
        printf("toogoo oruulna uu: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        
        i=0;
        while (f<=n){
            f = (9.0/5.0 * i) + 32;
            printf("%.1f\n", f);
            i++;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well 37.4 is smaller than 38 so what do you expect?

Comment: The value *was* less than your limit when it entered the loop. Just reorganise the loop logic.

Comment: The first time the value is tested is *undefined behaviour* since `f` has never been set. Try ``while ((f = (9.0/5.0 * i) + 32) <= n)``

Comment: `f` is used when not initialized. The initial value of local variables is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix

```
    while (1){
        f = (9.0/5.0 * i) + 32;
        if(f>n)                   // Move condition to after calculation
            break;
        printf("%.1f\n", f);
        i++;
    }
```

This will also solve the bug that you're using `f` before it's initialized.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
    int main(){
        int i, n;
        float f;
        printf("toogoo oruulna uu: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        
        i=0;
        f=0;
        while (f<=(n-1)){
            f = (9.0/5.0 * i) + 32;
            printf("%.1f\n", f);
            i++;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Look `while (f<=(n-1))` , the while loop will stop 1 iteration earlier and make sure you are setting the f variable with a value before you use it!